# Only First Source Plays for Array Number - No Other Sources Play

Tags: jquery, arrays, click, html5-audio

So, I'm trying to make an addition to this wack-a-mole game for school (this is extra, not required) to where whenever I click on Owen Wilson's face, one of the variations of the audio files will play. I have tried a plain array with the file names and that doesn't work, but the way I currently have it works in the way of only playing the first file, and never anything else. The click function works fine, the main problem is with either my HTML or JavaScript. I could not find anything exactly how I am wanting to do it online, and I am out of ideas.

HTML:

```
<audio id="wowFiles">
        <source src="wow/wow1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <source src="wow/wow2.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <source src="wow/wow3.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <source src="wow/wow4.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

JavaScript/JQuery:

```
function wow () {
          $("#wowFiles").src = $("#wowFiles source")[4];

          var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

          $("#wowFiles")[rand].play();
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the `audio` tag describes one audio file (in multiple formats if necessary). So you'll need to put each sound snippet in its own `audio` tag, then randomly select one of them.

Something like this should work:

```js
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

$(".wow")[rand].play();
```

```html
<audio class="wow">
    <source src="wow/wow1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<audio class="wow">
    <source src="wow/wow2.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<audio class="wow">
    <source src="wow/wow3.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<audio class="wow">
    <source src="wow/wow4.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```